# CSS image stripe hover effect not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

The title might be a little bit confusing. Let me explain my problem:
I am using CSS image stripes for social buttons. 
Here is a quick example:

```
.appnet {
     display:block;
     width:64px;
     height:64px;
     background: url('http://yanlu.de/files/images/SocialButtons.svg') no-repeat;
     background-position:-256px 0;
     margin-right: 10px;
     margin-left: 10px;
}
.appnet:hover {
     background-position:-256px -64px;
}
.appnet:active {
     background-position:-256px -128px;
}
```

Now there is my jQuery part:

```
$('.appnet').css('background-position','-256px -192px');
```

Now, while hovering the button there is no change of the image stripe. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are cascading styles by inline CSS.

Take a look at the example below:

**HTML**

```
<a href="">:hover is not working, yea?</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover {
  background-color: gold;
}

a {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**And finally the JS**

```
$('a').css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
```

**[JSBin Demo 1](http://jsbin.com/oqatur/1/edit)**

By using `jQuery.css();` method, you add the CSS as inline style to the selected element, which it has a higher priority than internal or external styles.

You can make the `:hover` declaration `!important` to set its priority higher:

```
a:hover {
  background-color: gold !important;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo 2](http://jsbin.com/oqatur/2/edit)**

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But do you have any idea how to fix it? I mean this line of code is used for when the website gets visited at night. (Then it has a dark background and so should the button)

Comment: @Yanlu You can use `!important` as I mentioned for general usage. but if you need to select only the `nightly` version of `.appnet` element. you can use `.appnet[style]:hover { property : value !important }`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be avoid doing the styling in your Javascript.

Instead have a 'dark' class

```
.dark {
    background-position: -256px -192px;
}
```

And just toggle it on and off as required.

```
$('.appnet').toggleClass('dark');
```